# Swift: How to find a replace a a group of characters in a string, starting from a predefined character and ending with another

Tags: swift, xcode, replace, range

I am currently working on a project, and am close to finishing.  I just have one problem.

I have extra random stuff in the string that I want to get rid of.  something like
""

What I want to do is this:

```
var infoFormat: String = "Hello, I like <ck4icl;alekdinl;dlke>pancakes!"
infoFormat = infoFormat.replacingOccurrences(of: "<" to ">", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)

print(infoFormat)
// prints "Hello, I like pancakes!"
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Much thanks to anyone that tries to help.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression removes all characters between `<` and `>`

```
var infoFormat = "Hello, I like <ck4icl;alekdinl;dlke>pancakes!"
infoFormat = infoFormat.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The pattern searches for `<` followed by one or more characters which are not `>` and a closing `>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let infoFormat: String = "Hello, I like <ck4icl;alekdinl;dlke>pancakes!"
    let stringFirstIndex = infoFormat.firstIndex(of: "<")
    let firstIndex = infoFormat.index(stringFirstIndex!, offsetBy: 0)
    let stringLastIndex = infoFormat.firstIndex(of: ">")
    let lastIndex = infoFormat.index(stringLastIndex!, offsetBy: 0)
    let finalString = infoFormat.replacingCharacters(in: firstIndex...lastIndex, with: "")
    print(finalString)
```

Make sure to safely unwrap the optional.

Answer (score 0):

Can try like:

```
var infoFormat = "Hello, I like <ck4icl;alekdinl;dlke>pancakes!"

    var startIndex = infoFormat.startIndex

    while let from = infoFormat.range(of: "<", range: startIndex..<infoFormat.endIndex)?.lowerBound,
        let to = infoFormat.range(of: ">", range: from..<infoFormat.endIndex)?.upperBound,
        from != to {
            infoFormat.removeSubrange(from..<to)
            startIndex = from
    }

    print(infoFormat)
    
    /// OR ///
    
    let parsed = infoFormat.replacingOccurrences(of: "<ck4icl;alekdinl;dlke>", with: "")
    print(parsed)
```

Note: You can use `replacingOccurrences` if you know the sub-string to remove, else use first one.

Output:

> Hello, I like pancakes!
>
> Hello, I like pancakes!

Thanks